# How to link StepDefination classes from Classpath (jar) in Cucumber IntelliJ Plugin

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-java

I would like to use existing step definition classes coming from maven jar dependency.

My cucumber tests works if ran from Runner Class (with glue to packages) & mvn CLI. But the 
problem is with IntelliJ Cucumber plugin for the steps which are coming from jar. In feature file steps that I am using from the jar are shown as "Undefined step reference:...".  I am not even able to run directly from feature file.

Is there a way I can configure cucumber plugin to use stepdefinations from classloader/jar?

Comment: Do you see the jar and its content in External Libraries in Project View?

Comment: Yes I do see. Test test runs fine if i run mvn clean test or if i run it from the runner class.  Only the problem is with running by Right click on scenario in feature file . and the feature file shows missing step.

Comment: I see there is a solution with EClipse Cucumber plugin. We can configure user settings inside cucumber plugin config. Unfortunately unable to find  same with intelliJ. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse/wiki/Reusing-Of-Step-Definitions-From-External-Class-Path-Dependencies%28JAR-POM...etc%29

Comment: Hi @Andrey Vokin, I found there is issue already created here. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-104610 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157652 , Can you please suggest any fix or workaround? like may be going to any config file and add glue path explicitly ? I really needed this working very badly. thank you so much in advance.

Comment: One of the post mentioning Added Source jar to repo and downloading Source Jar in dependent project worked for him with Java 7 . I use Java 8 and this solution did not work. Pease suggest some workaround

Comment: Could you provide jar with step definition to issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157652. I'll check if it's possible to support without attaching sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the solution worked for Me:

- Use IntelliJ 2020.1 +
- In cucumber run configuration : select jar manifest for classpath
- Deploy the Jar with source jar as well to Nexus as below

You can simple do this by adding `maven-source-plugin` plugin to your build

```
    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-sources</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>
```

- In other project add dependency and confirm source is downloaded from repo

File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> Select the Artifact -> Sources , Make sure it's not in red.

- Update IntelliJ to use latest version, for me IntelliJ version 2019 did not work but 2020.1 was able to find the step definitions.

**PS:** I use Java8 with Lambda exp and I can confirm it works.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Intellij from version 2019.3 to 2022.2 solved the issue without changing anything else.
My project is in Java 8